# Finding a flaw in a linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider $f(x, y, z) = (x^2 + 2y^2, x + z, x - z)$. Your friend wants to find the image of $f$, and their proof is the following:

We know that $w$ is in the image of $f$ if and only if there is a vector $v = (x, y, z)$ such that $f(v) = w$. Equivalently, there are $x, y, z$ such that $f(x, y, z) = w$. But this happens if and only if we can write $w = xf(1, 0, 0) + yf(0, 1, 0) + zf(0, 0, 1)$. This happens if and only if $w$ is in the span of $f(1, 0, 0)$, $f(0, 1, 0)$, and $f(0, 0, 1)$. Evaluating the function at these points, we conclude that this happens if and only if $w$ is in the span of $(1, 1, 1), (2, 0, 0)$, and $(0, 1, -1)$. Therefore, the image is equal to $(1, 1, 1), (2, 0, 0), (0, 1, -1)$.

- Is my friend's proof correct? If not, what is the mistake? If my friend is right, is $f$ onto?

I don't really see any mistakes in the proof. I was able to read through it all without any issue. The only questionable part for me is splitting $f(x, y, z)$ into $xf(1, 0, 00 + yf(0, 1, 0) + zf(0, 0, 1)$ but I can't quite justify why.

Now I have been struggling to show that the function is onto. I've looked at numerous examples, but I'm not really sure. I think it's enough for me to show that the span of the three vectors above is $\mathbb{R}^3$. But I don't think that this works because we can't get $(0, -1, 0)$. So I think the function is not onto.

Am I right?

Comment: Your $f$ is not a linear map, so using linear algebra arguments may not work.

Comment: In fact, *do* not work in this case.  Since the first entry, $\ x^2+2y^2\ $, of $\ f(x,y,z)\ $ is *always* non-negative, no element of $\ \mathbb{R}^3\ $ with a negative first entry can be in the image of $\ f\ $, so $\ f\ $ cannot possibly be onto the codomain $\ \mathbb{R}^3\ $.

Comment: The world would be a much easier place if everything is linear, so I understand the impulse...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: everything is linear... locally.

Comment: Not counting the gross mistake about linearity, the argument is plain wrong: the image is not the three vectors, it is the span of these vectors.

Answer (score 1):

As ancient mathematician points out in the comments, $f$ is **not** a linear map (the appearance of squares of variables should raise red flags!). That $f$ is not linear is further evidenced by the following:

\begin{eqnarray}
xf(1,0,0)+yf(0,1,0)+zf(0,0,1)&=&x(1,1,1)+y(2,0,0)+z(0,1,-1)\\
&=& (x+2y,x+z,x-z)\\
&\neq&f(x,y,z).
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, the 'splitting' part is simply false!